# Add five hours to timestamp field

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to add few hours eg: 5hours 30 mins to timestamp field using bigquery. My timestamp field is in the format - '2016-05-03 21:35:03'

How can i do this in bigquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  ts, 
  DATE_ADD(ts, 330, "MINUTE") AS ts_plus_530 
FROM 
  (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS ts),
  (SELECT TIMESTAMP("2016-05-03 21:35:03") AS ts)
```

See [DATE_ADD](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#date_add) for more details

Comment: This works for legacy SQL only - see @Ellot Brossard's answer for the standard SQL solution

Answer (score 14):

For completeness, the equivalent [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) query (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options") would be:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT ts
  FROM UNNEST([CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
               TIMESTAMP("2016-05-03 21:35:03")]) AS ts)
SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD(ts, INTERVAL 330 MINUTE) AS ts_plus_530
FROM T;
+---------------------+
|     ts_plus_530     |
+---------------------+
| 2016-08-09 04:18:05 |
| 2016-05-04 03:05:03 |
+---------------------+
```

Documentation for `TIMESTAMP_ADD` is here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#timestamp_add